# Does the Conservative Party of Canada have a ban on abortion in its platform?

Tags: politics, canada

It would either be an outright ban (outlawed) or a ban on the public funding part (health care being all public in Canada).

But I'm just asking: is there such a thing in their platform?

Comment: I think this question is off topic. It's the kind of political question that we don't want according to http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here

Comment: @Christian: I see the rule as wanting to avoid questions of the type "Is policy/opinion X good" which would arguably explode into endless debate, with several other venues more suitable to such discussions. My question is "Does X claim/have/is Y?" Potential answers are yes and no, and is most likely answerable (at a certain fix point in time, at least). Under that light, is my question still valid?

Comment: Uhm. Why don't you just ask them? How is this a "skeptics" question? :-)

Comment: @Lennart: If I want spin, I ask a politician. I don't want spin, I want fact. :)

Comment: In what sense do you consider the answer of some politician of the Conservative Party of Canada something different than the platform of the party? What do you mean exactly with the phrase "platform"?

Comment: @Christian: I mean in the party program. The one that's voted at the party convention and that constitutes the basic offer for electors to decide on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word *abortion* does not appear in the CPC 2011 platform [Here for Canada](http://www.conservative.ca/media/ConservativePlatform2011_ENs.pdf)

*Added:* In a [CBC interview in January](http://www.cbc.ca/thenational/indepthanalysis/story/2011/01/17/national-stephenharperinterview.html), Stephen Harper was asked whether he would re-open the abortion issue if his party won a majority. He replied:

> No, no. Look, Peter, I have
>   spent my political career trying to
>   stay out of that issue. It's one on
>   which people, including in my own
>   party, have passionate views. They're
>   all over the map. And you know, what I
>   say to people, as you know, many
>   people I know are pro-life. What I say
>   to people, if you want to diminish the
>   number of abortions, you've got to
>   change hearts and not laws. And I'm
>   not interested in having a debate over
>   abortion law.

Comment: I did that search too, I was wondering if there is something less campaign-y and more detailed. But thanks :)

Comment: How much more details do you need than "I don't want to do anything on this issue"

Comment: @DJClayworth, my comment was posted before the edit.

Comment: Sorry. In find it hard to remember questions might have been edited.